# How to replace the nested array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 79
            [logo] => 1463466926-97157549.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 78
            [logo] => 1463466942-15603675.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 77
            [logo] => 1463466953-25200244.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 76
            [logo] => 1463466967-62926110.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 75
            [logo] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 74
            [logo] => 
        )

)
```

Its my array values.

Here I send some values such as `hotel_id` & `logo` of that hotel..

But I should need to send the logo as image URL

i.e:,for this:`1463466926-97157549.jpg`
I need to send as
`http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/1463466926-97157549.jpg`

By adding the path of that image..

And finally my array should be like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 79
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/1463466926-97157549.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 78
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/1463466942-15603675.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 77
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/1463466953-25200244.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 76
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/1463466967-62926110.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 75
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/300x300.jpg
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 74
            [logo] => http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/300x300.jpg
        )

)
```

Here, the last two hotels having null images.

For that I send an default image URL such as *`http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/300x300.jpg`*

like this..

Someone could help me please..

Thanks in advance...

**I have tried like this**

```
$im =array();
foreach ($Roo as $key => $value) 
{
    $im[]=(\URL::to('').'/'.$value['logo']);
}
```

Here, *`\URL::to('').'/'`* is my path AND `$Roo` is my array

But,Instead it retrieve only the `logo` in separate array.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Very unclear and fuzzy ... I would suggest to change your question: what are the calls (inputs) you expect? What are the outputs? Could you provide a working case? Could you provide some tries you've done?

Comment: using foreach loop, traverse the whole array and replace your `logo` with new one if `hotel_id` is match.

Comment: @ Frayne Konok can you explain with an example..please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

loop through your array and update your array as follows :

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if ($value['logo'] != '') {
        $value['logo'] = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/'.$value['logo'];
    } else {
        $value['logo'] = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/300x300.jpg';
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Simple and easy :)..But I don't know why did you use `&` before `$value`,After adding that & only the results came

Comment: & is used as a reference. See what references are in http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Hoo fine..Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($hotel_details as $key => $detail) {

    if(!empty($detail['logo']) {

        $detail['logo'] = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/'.$detail['logo']
        $hotel_destails[$key] = $detail

    } else {

        $detail['logo'] = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/300x300.jpg'
        $hotel_destails[$key] = $detail

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your array name is `$arr`, so start traversing the whole array and replace your logo with new one if hotel_id is match.

Using the `&` you mean that the array is reference so what you change here must update in the main array, this is optional.

```
$path = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/';
$hotel_id = 79;

foreach($arr as $key => &$value){
    if($value['hotel_id'] == $hotel_id){
       $value['logo'] = $path.$value['logo'];
       break;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

> Note: If you want to change the whole array then it will be very easy,
>   just remove the if condition.

Comment: Thank you Frayne Konok,Why did you assign values for `hotel_id`,In my array the hotel_id could randomly changed as per my results

Comment: Why you use this line _Here I send some values such as hotel_id & logo of that hotel.._???

Answer (score 0):

There you should check about [`array_map()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

**With this entry array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 0
            [logo] => image_0.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 1
            [logo] => image_1.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 2
            [logo] => image_2.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 3
            [logo] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 4
            [logo] => image_4.jpg
        )

)
```

**You can get this output array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 0
            [logo] => http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/image_0.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 1
            [logo] => http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/image_1.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 2
            [logo] => http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/image_2.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 3
            [logo] => http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/300x300.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hotel_id] => 4
            [logo] => http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/image_4.jpg
        )

)
```

**By simply doing this :**

```
$base = 'http://some_addr.tld/some_dir/some_sub_dir/';

$default = '300x300.jpg';

$res = array_map(
    function($x) use ($base, $default)
    {
        if ( array_key_exists( 'logo', $x ) )
        {
            if ( !empty( $x['logo'] ) )
            {
                $x['logo'] = $base . $x['logo'];
            }
            else
            {
                $x['logo'] = $base . $default;
            }
        }

        return $x;
    }
    , $arr);
```

Where `$arr` is the array containing your hotels, and `$res` will be the modified array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do achieve this by following code:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/abservetech/laravel/abserve_crud_travelz/public/';
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if ($value['logo'] != '') {
        $value['logo'] = $url.$value['logo'];
    } else {
        $value['logo'] = $url;
    }
}
```